# Not getting json data from json-angularjs call to an external url with $http.get using success method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, model-view-controller

Controller.js file code:

```
var myApp=angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myController', function($scope,$http){

    $http.get('data.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.art=data;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: $scope.art=data; replace data with response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assign response to `$scope.art`

```
var myApp=angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myController', function($scope,$http){

    $http.get('data.json').success(function(response){
        $scope.art=response;
    }); 
});
```

**Note** : The deprecated .success and .error methods have been removed from AngularJS 1.6

Using `.then`

```
var myApp=angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myController', function($scope,$http){

    $http.get('data.json').then(function(response){
        $scope.art=response.data;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: What is your angular version and what does your  response contain?

Comment: It is showing following error: TypeError: $http.get(...).success is not a function

Comment: It is because you are using newer version of angularjs where  .success and .error methods have been deprecated. Instead use .then

Answer (score 2):

```
var myApp=angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myController', function($scope,$http){

    $http.get('data.json').then(function(response){
        $scope.art=response.data;
    }); 
});
```

Try with above. Might help!!

Comment: My pleasure I have been helpful.